# Convert a list of sf objects into one sf

Tags: r, list, data.table, rbind, r-sf

I have a list of `sf` objects that I would like to row bind to create a single `sf` object. I'm looking for a function similar to `data.table::rbindlist`, that would stack the individual objects in an efficient manner.

#### Data for reproducible example:

```
my_list <- structure(list(structure(list(idhex = 4L, geometry = structure(list(
            structure(c(664106.970004623, 6524137.38910266), class = c("XY", 
            "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 664106.970004623, 
            ymin = 6524137.38910266, xmax = 664106.970004623, ymax = 6524137.38910266
            ), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(epsg = 32633L, proj4string = "+proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = 1L, class = c("sf", 
            "data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(idhex = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", 
            "aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor")), structure(list(
            idhex = 9, geometry = structure(list(structure(c(665491.220375992, 
            6525002.7560692), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", 
            "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 665491.220375992, 
            ymin = 6525002.7560692, xmax = 665491.220375992, ymax = 6525002.7560692
            ), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(epsg = 32633L, proj4string = "+proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = 1L, class = c("sf", 
            "data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(idhex = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", 
            "aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"))), .Dim = 1:2, .Dimnames = list(
            ".", NULL))
```

Note that `data.table` and `sf` libraries are not entirely compatible yet. So the `rbindlist` function returns an object that is not recognized as an `sf object.

```
single_sf <- rbindlist(my_list)
class(single_sf)
```

Comment: Though you can easily convert to a sf (if the crs are equivalent) `sf::st_as_sf(data.table::rbindlist(my_list))`

Comment: For completeness, @timelyportfolio also wrote `mapedit:::combine_list_of_sf` to achieve this. It may also be worth monitoring https://github.com/r-spatial/mapedit/issues/46 as a dedicated `bind_rows_sf` may be implemented in **sf** at some stage.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
df <- do.call(rbind, my_list)

> class(df)
[1] "sf"         "data.frame"
```

It is worth noting that `dplyr::bind_rows` and `purrr::map_dfr` does not work with sf objects, and thus `rbind` is better in this case.

Comment: It is also worth noting that the crs of the list elements need to match...

Answer (score 10):

This is an old question but it is worth to note that the recent version of `dplyr` (> 0.9) can bind rows of `sf` objects (in a list or not):

```
single_sf <- dplyr::bind_rows(my_list)
class(single_sf)
[1] "sf"         "data.frame"
```

Other packages also provide options that can be used for binding `sf` objects (e.g.
`mapedit:::combine_list_of_sf()`, `sf:::rbind.sf` and `data.table::rbindlist`), besides the `do.call()` option mentioned above (see https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/798# for a discussion and some benchmarking). But the `dplyr` option also works for `sf` objects with data frames containing different number of columns, somenthing that `do.call()`, `sf:::rbind.sf()`, and `data.table::rbindlist()` cannot do, and was important for me working with a list of `sf` objects with different number of columns.

Answer (score 3):

I've found the fastest approach to do this is using `data.table::rbindlist` and then converting back to `sf`, as follows:

```
library(sf)
library(data.table)

# fast row bind
sf <- rbindlist(my_list)

# back to st
sf <- st_sf(sf)
```