# Apply different sf functions to groups in a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, r-sf

I'm trying to calculate different Euclidean buffers (one 400m and one 800m) within a single simple features data frame using a set of piped dplyr function calls. The buffer distance should be specified for each feature based on the value of a grouping variable. I could easily split the data frame based on known values of the grouping variable, but I'd like to make the method as general as possible.

The following code works, but obviously only returns a single 400m buffer for all groups:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(42)
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
nc$grp <- sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 100)

nc_buff <- nc %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  st_transform(32119) %>%
  group_map(~ st_buffer(.x, 400))
```

Ideally I'd split the data frame, calculate each buffer, and return a single simple features data frame with both sets of buffers combined.

How can I return a single data frame that contains a 400m buffer for grp == 0 and an 800m buffer for grp == 1?

Comment: This is helpful. If I try this:
`nc_buff <- nc %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  st_transform(32119) %>%
  group_modify(~ st_buffer(.x, case_when(.y == 0 ~ 400, .y == 1 ~ 800)))
`
It seems like the geometry information in the resultant sf data frame gets lost. Can you post the code you used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not actually need to `group` the data amd use `group_map`. You
can infact pass a vector of buffer widths directly to `st_buffer`:

```r
library(sf)
library(dplyr) 
set.seed(42)
nc <- st_read(system.file("/shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>% 
    st_transform(32119) %>%
    st_centroid() %>% 
    mutate(grp = sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = TRUE))
```

Here, I “create” the buffer width column on-the-fly

```r
nc_buff <- nc %>%
  st_buffer(., ifelse(.$grp == 0, 4000, 8000))

plot(nc_buff["NAME"])
```

[image]

For more complex cases or impreved readability, you can also use a mutate to create the buffer column beforehand, using for example `ifelse` or `case_when`:

```r
 nc_buff <- nc %>%
  mutate(buf_wdt = ifelse(.$grp == 0, 4000, 8000)) %>% 
  st_buffer(., .$buf_wdt) %>% 
  select(-buf_wdt)
```

HTH!

<sup>Created on 2019-12-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This works brilliantly, thanks! Was not obvious to me that it was possible to pass a vector to `st_buffer()` but the help does say that dist defines the "buffer distance for all, or for each of the elements in x."

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this does the trick. `bind_rows()` is pipeable but doesn't currently work correctly on simple features data frames.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(42)
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
nc$grp <- sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 100)

nc_buff <- nc %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  st_transform(32119) %>%
  group_map(~ st_buffer(.x, case_when(.y$grp == 0 ~ 400, .y$grp == 1 ~ 800)))

# No way to bind_rows() with sf data frames yet so this extra step is needed
# https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/798
nc_buff <- do.call(rbind, nc_buff)
```

Note: Similar reasoning for preferring `do.call(rbind, )` over `bind_rows()` is given here: [Convert a list of sf objects into one sf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51312935/convert-a-list-of-sf-objects-into-one-sf).