# How to merge multiple sf polygons?

Tags: r, merge, gis, spatial, r-sf

I am having trouble finding the best way to merge multiple sf polygons into one new sf polygon. I have been using `st_union` however that seems to only merge two sf objects pairwise.

The `%>%` notation works to pipe a bunch of `st_union` functions, but there must be a different way?

```
all <- st_union(rd) %>% st_union(cb) %>%  st_union(pl) %>% st_union(sl) %>%  
       st_union(wp) %>%  st_union(wf) %>%  st_union(bd)
```

Also I find performance is really slow...

Comment: does cbind() work?

Comment: cbind() looks to append multiple geometries into the data.frame, however I need the output to have dissolved geometry

Answer (score 9):

This solution works for me:

```
single_sf <- dplyr::bind_rows(list(rd,cb,pl,sl,wp,wf,bd))
dissolve_sf <- st_union(single_sf)
```

Credit goes to this post: [Convert a list of sf objects into one sf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51312935/convert-a-list-of-sf-objects-into-one-sf)

Answer (score 1):

There is a list/array object for sf objects called `sfc` we can construct this list using `st_sfc(rd, cb, pl)` and we can then combine these objects using `sf_combine`.

If I have understood correctly this can be seen in more detail:

https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/sfc.html

and

https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/geos_combine.html

All together I would expect the code to look like the following:

```r
sfg_list <- st_sfc(rd, sb, pl, sl, wp, wf, bd)

st_combine(sfg_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the polygons are in a list, try

```
st_combine(do.call("c", pol))
```