# How can I perform a function on a list of dataframes and return a unique sf object for each?

Tags: r, lapply, r-sf

I have many dataframes with coordinate information.

```
losangeles <- data.frame(name=c("LA"),
                         lon = c(-118.2615805), 
                         lat = c(34.1168926))

toronto <- data.frame(name = c("toronto"), 
                      lon = c(-79.450717), 
                      lat = c(43.691589))
```

I have created a function that takes a dataframe and turns it into an sf object:

```
df_to_sf <- function(city){
  st_as_sf(city, 
           coords = c("lon","lat"),
           crs=4617)
}
```

What I would like is instead of having to write out this function many times to perform it on each of my dataframes, I would like to feed this function a list of my dataframes, perform the function on each dataframe, and return an sf object with the same name as its dataframe for each dataframe. Something like,

```
for dataframe in list_of_dataframes, 
apply function 
return sf object with name = name of dataframe
```

For example, if I perform the function on just one dataframe:

```
toronto <- df_to_sf(toronto)
```

I get my desired output, which is as simple feature collection:

```
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 1 field
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -79.45072 ymin: 43.69159 xmax: -79.45072 ymax: 43.69159
Geodetic CRS:  NAD83(CSRS)
     name                   geometry
1 toronto POINT (-79.45072 43.69159)
```

So far, I have been exploring the `lapply` function:

```
#create list of dataframes
df_list <- list(losangeles,toronto)

#apply function to each dataframe in list
lapply(names(df_list), function(x) df_to_sf(df_list[[x]]))
```

However I can only manage to return a list of dataframes using this, which is not what I want.

EDIT2:

It is not quite what I am looking for, but the most useful answer I have found is to use `rbind` to merge my sf dataframes into one feature collection. However this isn't an answer to my question, which is how to create individual feature collections from each dataframe I feed into my function. But here is where I have gotten so far:

```
library(tidyverse)

los <- data.frame(name=c("LA"),
                         lon = c(-118.2615805), 
                         lat = c(34.1168926))

toro <- data.frame(name = c("toronto"), 
                      lon = c(-79.450717), 
                      lat = c(43.691589))

#Dataframe to sf object function
df_to_sf <- function(city){
  st_as_sf(city, 
           coords = c("lon","lat"),
           crs=4617)
}

#create list of dataframes
df_list <- tibble::lst(los,toro)

#apply function to each dataframe in the list
list_of_sfs<- lapply(names(df_list), function(x) df_to_sf(df_list[[x]]))

#bind sfs to one sf object
feature_collection = do.call(rbind, list_of_sfs)
```

EDIT:

I have also now tried to use the `tibble::lst` function to name my list objects in `df_list`, but this gives me the same final result as not using this function:

```
#create list 
df_list <- tibble::lst(losangeles,toronto)

#apply function to each dataframe in the list
result<- lapply(names(df_list), function(x) df_to_sf(df_list[[x]]))
```

The result is still just a list of two dataframes that don't have a name.

Comment: [some approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51312935/convert-a-list-of-sf-objects-into-one-sf).

Comment: `lapply(df_list, df_to_sf)` will return a `list` of `sf` objects. I think perhaps your problem is that lists are not named by default. `list(losangeles,toronto)` is not a named list--the names are `NULL`.

Comment: Here's some approaches to creating lists with names: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16951080/903061

Comment: @GregorThomas I tried this (adding to my question now) but this still gave me the same result as before when using lapply (a list of two unnamed dataframes)

Comment: @Chris  I am editing my question to add your comment as a very close answer to what I am looking for (but not quite). Because while it is helpful to use rbind to get my sf objects into one feature collection, I am looking to create individual feature collections from each data frame I feed into my function.

Comment: perhaps: `lapply(df_list, \(x) { sfheaders::sf_point(obj = x, x = "lon", y = "lat", keep = T) }) ` ? as a starting point? It will need a slight adjustment to put the CRS on each object.